# Least-squares method with a cubic curve

Tags: numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, least-squares

> The speed $v$ of a ship is related to the power $p$ of its engine by the empirical formula $$p=a+bv^3$$ Determine the values of $a$ and $b$ in the least squares sense from the following experimental data:
>
> $$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
> \hline 
> v & 6 & 8 & 10 & 12 \\ \hline
> p & 420 & 805 & 1370 & 2370 \\ \hline
> \end{array}$$
>
> [ Source: $\small\textit{ A Theoretical Introduction to Numerical Analysis, Ryaben'kii & Tsyknov} ]$

I know how to solve a least squares system where the variables are linear. However, $v^3$ is not linear and I'm not sure what to do. Do I do the same thing, using:

$$\phi(a,b) = \sum_{k=1}^{4} [a+bv_k^3-p]^2 = [a+6^3b-420]^2...$$

and solve? Or is there a way to account for the cube?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $w=v^3$, for each $v$, you should be able to compute the corresponding $w$.

Now solve for $a$ and $b$ in $p=a+bw$.

While the problem is not linear in $v$, it is linear in $v^3=w$.

Your approach is correct.